# "Человек плохо воспитанный" - см. в контексте

Tags: пунктуация

> Поэтому я и говорю, что очень важно тратить время на своих детей и
>   помогать им. Потому что хорошо воспитанный человек отличается от
>   человека плохо воспитанного именно тем, что он очень точно и адекватно
>   существует и действует по отношению к реальности.

Если я обособлю "плохо воспитанного", то "хорошо воспитанный человек" не помешает обособлению?

Comment: Думаю, что обособлять можно только при порядке слов "человека, воспитанного плохо" (ср. "человек, ходящий прямо" и "человек прямоходящий").

Comment: Не режет ли вам слух "адекватно существует",  "существует и действует"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Потому что хорошо воспитанный человек отличается от человека плохо воспитанного...***

Запятыми  *"плохо воспитанного"* в разбираемом предложении выделять не стоит.

Вот как соответствующее этому случаю правило сформулировано у [**Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)

> **§ 18…** Не обособляются распространенные определения:
>
> <…>
>
> 2) стоящие после определяемого существительного, если последнее само
>   по себе в данном предложении не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в
>   определении:
>
> *Если вы **человек себя уважающий…** то непременно напроситесь на ругательства.*
>
> *Все они оказались **учениками хорошо подготовленными**.*

То же и здесь:

> *Эти писатели выражали интересы не предреволюционной буржуазии, а **буржуазии уже победившей**.*

(Пример взят из книги Былинского и Розенталя *"Трудные случаи пунктуации"*, М., 1959).

Answer (score 2):

"Плохо воспитанного" обособлять в данном случае не стоит не потому, что это инверсия, а потому, что при инверсии и отсутствии обособления **логически выделяется определение.**

Answer (score 1):

"Плохо воспитанного" обособлять в данном контексте не стоит, т.к. это инверсия.